# Intro image component for joomla 1.7

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.7

Are there any components that allow uploading an intro image via the article like Joomla 2.5 in Joomla 1.7?

I've searched on google but no luck. Is there any tutorial for adding in this function in Joomla 1.7?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it with a form plugin, but you should not be on 1.7, it is past end of life.

Comment: yah. i wish i could turn the current joomla 1.7 site into 2.5, but the updating processes failed with error 'copy files failed'. no clue at all on which part has to be fix.

Comment: You're using the updater? You can also do the update by using the extension installer, that may work for you.

Comment: Also I looked on the forums and as I thought that i probably due to a problem with file ownership.  YOu could enable the ftp layer (you'll have to edit the configuration file manually probably) and install the update as an extension.

Comment: i have checked both. files and folders permission is 777. not to waste much of time, wat i did is copy and paste the joomla 2.5 update stable version files to my current joomla 1.7. another fatal error appeared (Fatal error: Call to a member function getKeyName() on a non-object in /home/username/domains/username.com.my/public_html/libraries/joomla/application/component/modeladmin.php on line 801) when i try to add new article

Comment: File permissions and file ownership  are two different things.
After you copy the files make sure to visit the database tab to get all of the schema updates (click the fix button).

Comment: yup. follow the instruction in joomla doc. and correct all the files and folders ownership too. But still no luck in upgrading to joomla 2.5. the only reason i would like to have the intro image is because i hope there will be image for each intro article in blog view layout but not in the single article view. and i didn't realised that there's a hide intro text function available in joomla until today.

Comment: Yup that's exactly what that option is for.

Do you have a stacktrace for that error?

Comment: nope. nvr tried before to stack trace joomla code. you mind to share with me the quickest way to debug joomla code?

Comment: In Global Configuration turn error reporting to Development and turn on the debugging. THat gets you started anyway.